# Is there any way to completely move an element position depending on screen size ? CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

So I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS for now, and not getting yet into jvS. I'm trying to create a responsive design, and I understand media queries somehow.

Basically, I have a screen-size width nav bar on the desktop with a logo in it. When I get to phone sizes, I want that logo to move on the right bottom corner of the screen and be sticky there.

Do you know that + sign on Twitter when you want to post? I want to do something like that. BUT I want to know if I can just move the element I already created for the navbar, or do I need a completely new element?

This is in HTML

```css
header {
    background-color: chartreuse;
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="/Assets/Logo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav>
        <ul class = "links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Youtube</button> </a>
</header>
```

And I basically need that logo to move on the right bottom of the screen on screen sizes smaller than 500px. I can't find any answers, so if you have any suggestions please help me!

Comment: Read about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by utilizing `position: fixed`. This rule assigns **fixed positioning** on an element, which in other words means no matter how horizontally or vertically big is your page, the element will stay in the same place.

`poistion: fixed` works almost the same way as `position: absolute`. You specify the element's positioning, according to the parent relative element. This is the css you're looking for:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that every parent element (every element above the image) **cannot** have `position: relative`, because the `bottom` and `right` rules will count from the bottom and right section of the relative element. The only tag above the image you can specify `position: relative` to, is either `body` or `html`.

Comment: Okay, I am open to judgement, but how is it completely wrong can I ask? Because I think I gave him a working code snippet, much like what you answered above. Actually, you essentially went ahead and described the very thing I did.

Comment: 1.) fixed position isn't relative to any element, but to the viewport/screen. relatively positioned elements don't play any role for fixed positioned elements. 2.) relative position can be applied to *any* block element 3.) The "anchor" for an absolutely positioned element is the next higher parent element which has `position: relative`

Comment: Concerning #2 and #3, you wrote: "The only tag above the image you can specify position: relative to, is either body or html". And I certainly didn't copy your answer, since it's 80% wrong.

Comment: Ok so I added  

''' position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
'''
The problem is that, for some reason my element sticks to the right top corner instead of the bottom one O;o

Answer (score 0):

To take an element out of the document flow and fix it at a particular position on the screen, you can use `position: fixed` and the top/bottom/left/right parameters, and you can put all that into a media query to apply it only below a certain screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. These guys helped me with the position:fixed.

My problem then was that for some reason bottom:0 and right:0 would put my logo on top instead of the bottom. That was because I had another media query on it for earlier when I tried different stuff, and forgot about it.

Thank you for help!